How to add super-space aka s-SPC as leader-key in exwm?
How can I access the leader key in e.g. Firefox buffer using s-SPC?
Whatever I try, I'm either getting nothing in char mode or s-SPC is undefined in line mode.
Examples:
;; config.el
(push (aref (kbd "s-<SPC>") 0) exwm-input-prefix-keys)
(push (aref (kbd "s-SPC") 0) exwm-input-prefix-keys)
(push ?\s-\  exwm-input-prefix-keys) ;; note double whitespace after the second backslash

In short I'm trying to replicate the perfectly working s-SPC leader key behaviour from this spacemacs layer
I read the exwm wiki,in particular global-key-bindings alongside doom leader keys

According to this page the super key can be emulated with C-x @ s; in windows or Mac we can use the right-modifier-key, however your use case is not revealed. Maybe it will be a good idea to use that keybinding without make it a leader key.
